# Flutter: How to play and pause audio using the same button as countdown start button?

Tags: flutter

I have a play pause button for a countdown timer. When I press play, the timer starts, at the same time I was the audio to play as well. How should I implement this?

Note: the most of the counter code is in another file. Just wanted to get the play/pause for audio working first in the same onPressed for now.

Below is what I have so far:

Updated: I think I messed up somewhere. I'm not able to pause the audio now. I have been trying few of the flutter audioplayer tutorials but I'm not able figure out how to implement both countdown and audio action with a single play pause button

```
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';

import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

class Jiddu extends StatefulWidget {
  const Jiddu({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _JidduState createState() => _JidduState();
}

class _JidduState extends State<Jiddu> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;
  AudioPlayer _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  bool isPlaying = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 60),
    );
      _audioCache = AudioCache(
        prefix: "audio/",
        fixedPlayer: AudioPlayer()..setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.STOP));
  }

  playme() async {
  AudioPlayer audioplay = await _audioCache.play('30sec.mp3');
  }

  AudioCache _audioCache;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Audio')),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
              child: RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  child: Text('Go Back'))),
          Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  FloatingActionButton(
                    child: AnimatedBuilder(
                      animation: controller,
                      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                        return new Icon(controller.isAnimating
                            ? Icons.pause
                            : Icons.play_arrow);
                      },
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (controller.isAnimating && isPlaying){
                        controller.stop();

                     } else {
                        controller.reverse(
                            from: controller.value == 0.0
                                ? 1.0
                                : controller.value);    
                        playme();
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define your function to your condition in onPressed.

It could be like:

```
 onPressed: () {
                        if (controller.isAnimating)
                          controller.stop();
                        else {
                          playaudio(); // or what is your function for this
                          controller.reverse(
                              from: controller.value == 0.0
                                  ? 1.0
                                  : controller.value);
                        }
                        setState(() {
                          _visible = !_visible;
                        });
                      },
```

Comment: hey! I just updated my original post with my full code. Please have a look.